# Getting the wrong font awesome icon via npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, font-awesome

I am trying to upgrade my font awesome icons. Currently the `BellIcon` component returns this [font awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/bell?style=solid), where as I want it to return [this icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/bell). What am I doing wrong and how do I import the correct icon? Thanks.

**Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faBell} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

const BellIcon = () => {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBell} />
  );
};

export default BellIcon;
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.2.0",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-14",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.0-11",
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: Looks like the icon you want is from `v4.7.0`. Have you tried including that version?

Comment: @sliptype, how do I do that? Do I just downgrade one of my dependencies? What if I wanted to still have my dependencies rely on font awesome 5+?

Comment: you can downgrade just the dependency that includes that icon. I think it might be `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`. Try `npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@4.7.0`

Comment: Thanks @sliptype, but it looks like fortawesome is only supports font awesome 5+ icons: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome